# Braided monoidal categories as generalized "braided" schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, monoidal-categories, noncommutative-geometry

It's well know by the Gabriel-Rosenberg reconstruction theorem that a (quasi-separated) scheme $X$ is completely determined by its category of quasicoherent sheaves $\mathbf{QCoh}(X)$. The latter is always a symmetric monoidal category, so one can develop the viewpoint that identifies a symmetric monoidal category with a scheme or generalization thereof.

One can also, by way of this viewpoint, *define* non-symmetric monoidal categories (with some extra structure) as non-commutative schemes., see, e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611806). But what if we don't go all the way to remove all symmetry conditions, but instead allow the category to have a non-symmetric braiding?

Has any work been done in this direction? I can expect potential connections to TQFT and knot theory.

Comment: I think the premise of your question is based on the last sentence of your first paragraph. You say you can identify symmetric monoidal ab categories with schemes or generalizations of thereof but I'm not sure how this identification actually goes. There are abelian categories not equivalent to QCoh(X) for any commutative scheme X and which do admit symmetric monoidal structures (plural) so among the symmetric ones you already have noncommutative schemes (in the Gabriel-Rosenberg sense) with extra structure. The first question is: What do symmetric monoidal abelian categories do correspond to?

Comment: @AT0 Yeah, that's what I thought, so perhaps "view as an alternative of" might be more appropriate. I'd say it could even be a generalization, though not as vast as the "totally non-symmetric" case. Martin Brandenburg's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716) has some great ideas in this deparment